# Launching Blender seems to have messed up my microphone input to now pickup a radio signal

Tags: audio, installation

After installing Blender and launching it, I noticed a console popup with errors that goes away shortly, followed by the program opening seemingly fine.

I didn't have time to read those errors so I hit my Shadowplay Instant Replay recording hotkey. Upon playback, I could read it. (Here's a screenshot:)
[image]

It got weird fast, because then [I could hear in my Shadowplay recording, for the first time ever, a radio signal](https://www.reddit.com/r/GeForceExperience/comments/84eb1m/shadowplay_is_picking_up_a_radio_signal/).

This happens with different microphones, too, including having no microphone in, so it's not a hardware issue! What could I do to fix my microphone input? I've since uninstalled Blender and am frustrated to have a problematic microphone channel on my computer now.

UPDATE:
After uninstalling and reinstalling Blender, and also doing the same with the OpenAL library that seems to be related, I'm still having radio recorded on my mic channel.

UPDATE:
It seems to stop happening temporarily sometimes. Haven't figured out the pattern.

Comment: Blender might be opening a channel you didn't normally have active. Which means that your gear always picks up radio signals? In Blender User preferences you can switch off openAL (if you think thats a problem). can you try booting in another OS, I assume you are on linux? But honestly it could be anything.

Comment: Make sure your PC is properly grounded, and that all recording volume slides are all the way down (except for the channel you want to use).